# Does fetchmail support SSL or TLS when using SMTP to forward email?

Tags: email, ssl, fetchmail, tls

I am trying to forward emails that are fetched with `fetchmail` to another SMTP host, which enforces `STARTTLS`. I could not find a way to enable TLS in `fetchmail`. Is this possible at all? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not appear that `fetchmail` supports TLS to the SMTP server.  This is normally not a problem, as it usually delivers emails locally.

You can work around this by delivering to a local SMTP server and have it handle the delivery.  If your don't need or want a full service server like `exim4` or `postfix`, you can use a light-weight relay like `esmtp` or 'msmtp` to deliver the mail.

---

Comment: Actually your recommendation is what I did. I used `msmtp` to forward the mail. It's a nice tool and supports TLS.