# Fetchmail fails to deliver mail locally due to enforced STARTTLS

Tags: security, encryption, postfix, fetchmail

I have setup a local mail server using `postfix` and `dovecot`. I now want `fetchmail` to get my mails from another server and deliver them locally. I am getting errors, however, since `fetchmail` does not use `STARTTLS` when connecting via `SMTP` to the local `postfix`:

```
reading message 852 of 853 (18519 octets) (log message incomplete)
SMTP> MAIL FROM:<XXXXXXXXXXX> SIZE=18519
SMTP< 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
SMTP error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
SMTP server requires STARTTLS, keeping message.
SMTP> RSET
```

According to [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150379/does-fetchmail-support-ssl-or-tls-when-using-smtp-to-forward-email?newreg=dfaed04d15c241a8baa9b59669666840) this is because `fetchmail` does not support `STARTTLS` when talking to an `SMTP` server and states that it

> is normally not a problem, as it usually delivers emails locally.

I therefore conclude that my configuration is flawed in some way. I want connections to `postfix` to be secure when a MUA delivers mail but obviously I cannot enforce it if I want to use `fetchmail`. Is it the way to go to relax the security constraints in postfix's `master.cf` for `SMTP` and only enforce `STARTTLS` for `SUBMISSION`?

Comment: Could you instead have `fetchmail` talk directly to the mail delivery agent and cut Postfix out of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found [this solution](https://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=125252467602362&w=2) from Mr Postfix himself:

```
/etc/postfix/master.cf:

192.168.1.1:smtp  inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  127.0.0.1:smtp  inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
            -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
```

This, together with `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt` in [main.cf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) (as a global setting) should do the trick.